# Can I span conduit 15 feet between my home and unattached garage?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a porch separating my two bay garage and was looking to add a subpanel to the garage. The porch is attached to my house and butted against the garage, but not mechanically fastened to the garage. Can I hang the wiring (in conduit) vs burying the wiring?

Comment: Please [merge your guest and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Comment: I am guessing no.   Answers might tell you yes or no.   But the only person that can answer this for you truly is your local inspector.

Comment: what kind of a porch?

Comment: What is the porch made of?  is it covered?  Are you planning on covering it (Would allow you to go the garage in the rain...)  If it's wood porch can you run the conduit on the underside of the porch?  If you are going to cover the porch, you can hang it on the cover.

Answer (score 2):

You could also fabricate a "strut"* structure to span the distance, then strap the conduit to the strut. The issue is that you can't rely on the mechanical strength of the conduit to support itself (and the wire inside of it) for distances over 10ft.

*(Unitstrut or Superstrut are brands of construction members for making light frameworks for holding pipes and conduits typically sold at plumbing and electrical supply houses, but sometimes available at larger home centers)

http://www.tnb.com/pub/en/brands/superstrut

https://www.unistrut.us/

Answer (score 0):

Normally metal conduit has to be supported at 10' intervals. The question would be what size and type of conduit. You could construct some triangle braces extending from each building to support the conduit as long as the span between the 2 support points is less than 10'. If using rigid PVC it depends on the size per table 352.30 of the NEC. For example 1/2 to 1" requires supports every 3'. 1-1/4 to 2" every 5'.  Hope this helps.